# Send multiple integers to web service function

Tags: c#, web-services, sum

I have the following web service function-

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Sum(double a, double b);

}
public class Test : ITest
{
    public double Sum(double a, double b)
    {
        double answer = a + b;
        return answer;
    }
```

And I am implementing it using this -

```
        double a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        double sum = sc.Sum(a, b);
```

My problem being this only handles two doubles, how could I get it to handle several from just one text box, i.e. `1,2,3,4` with the response being `10`?

Comment: Consider using double.TryParse - double.Parse will throw an exception if the text is not formatted as a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it wasn't a web service you could use a special keyword `params`, like

```
public double Sum(params double[] items)
{
    //do sum
    return answer;
}
```

But web services don't know what `params` means so you would need to use something like `List<double>` or `double[]`, e.g.

```
public double Sum(List<double> items)
{
    return items.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the signature to take a string instead of two doubles.

Another option if you parse the doubles on the client side is to change the method to accept an params array of doubles.

```
[OperationContract]
double Sum(params double[] myParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be handled in one like you explained then you could first `.Split()` the textbox text

```
string[] numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
```

Now that you have them separated convert them to doubles

```
double[] doubleNumbers = new double[numbers.Count];
int counter = 0;
foreach(string s in numbers)
{
    doubleNumbers[counter++] = Double.Parse(s);
}
```

Then just send it to your sum function

```
 Sum(doubleNumbers);

 private static void Sum(params double[] list)
 {
     double sum = 0;
     foreach (double number in list)
     {
         sum += number;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(sum);
 }
```